# How should I handle error of incorrect format JSON response against my object model? [ES6]

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

Suppose I have a backend API service that returns a JSON object of employee

```js
{
  id: '1',
  first_name: 'John',
  last_name: 'Doe'
}
```

And, in my Front-end app, I created a model of exactly same format as the expected JSON response from backend

```js
class Employee {
  id: string;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string
}
```

My app will behave correctly without any error, until one day, the backend engineer decided to change the JSON object to

```js
{
  id: '1',
  fname: 'John',
  lname: 'Doe'
}
```

As the guy who handles the front-end code, how should I handle the behaviour of my app, so it doesn't blatantly throw unexpected behaviour to user's face.

Comment: If only response structure changed, you should also adopt that change in your front end. What is issue than?

Comment: your backend engineer shouldnt be changing production code directly to throw error to the end user..

Comment: What else could it do than blatantly throwing an error?

Comment: If, in fact it happens, should I show the incomplete result to the user or just throw error stating 'Something's wrong'

Comment: Yes, "something is wrong", possibly also indicating that it's not the users fault, they cannot do anything about it (or when they do, what they should do), and that you're already working on resolving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are passing object to your constructor function you can set default values using `||` in case there is no specific `key` in object.

```js
class Employee {
 constructor(params) {
  this.id = params.id || 'default value';
  this.first_name = params.first_name || params.fname || 'default value';
  this.last_name = params.last_name || params.lname || 'default value';
 }
}

var e = new Employee({
  id: '1',
  fname: 'John',
  lname: 'Doe'
})

console.log(e)
```

Comment: well it wouldnt throw error but it wouldnt pass the value either :)

Comment: Change default to `params.fname` and so on. If that helps :)

Comment: @SuryaPurohit assuming backend engineer changes to that particular variable name